# How do I filter Firestore data?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview

My app allows `Users` to create `Charts`, which are stored in the Firestore database like this:

```
charts
    > documentKey1 
         > description = "Example description"
         > name = "Chart name 1"
         > uId = user1Id_string
    > documentKey2
         > description = "Another example description"
         > name = "Chart name 2"
         > uId = user2Id_string
    > documentKey3 
         > description = "Example description again"
         > name = "Chart name 3"
         > uId = user1Id_string
```

Each User can have multiple Charts. Currently, my `MainActivity` retrieves all of the current user's charts from the database, sorts them into a given order (set by the user), and shows them in a FirebaseRecyclerView within a Fragment.

The MainActivity has 2 Fragments in a ViewPager.  The relevant one is FragmentMyCharts which contains:

```
public class FragmentMyCharts extends FragmentChartsList {

    public FragmentMyCharts() {}

    public Query getQuery(FirebaseFirestore databaseReference,
                                String orderBy,
                                Query.Direction direction) {

            // Specify the query which is used to retrieve this user's charts
            return databaseReference.collection("charts")
                    .whereEqualTo("uid", getUid())
                    .orderBy(orderBy, direction);

    }

}
```

This extends FragmentChartsList, which is as follows:

```
public abstract class FragmentChartsList extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseFirestore mDatabaseRef;
    private ChartListAdapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView mRecycler;
    private String mOrder = "name", mFilter;
    private Query.Direction mDirection = Query.Direction.DESCENDING;

    private TextView mLoadingList, mEmptyList;


    public FragmentChartsList() {}

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

        // Inflate layout, and find Recycler View which will hold the list
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(
                R.layout.fragment_charts_list, container, false);

        mRecycler = rootView.findViewById(R.id.charts_list);
        mRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLoadingList = rootView.findViewById(R.id.loading_list);
        mEmptyList = rootView.findViewById(R.id.empty_list);

        // Set up Layout Manager, and set Recycler View to use it
        LinearLayoutManager mManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        mManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        mManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
        mRecycler.setLayoutManager(mManager);

        // Connect to the database
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        setOrderAndFilter(mOrder, mDirection, mFilter);

        return rootView;
    }

    public abstract Query getQuery(FirebaseFirestore databaseReference,
                                   String orderBy,
                                   Query.Direction direction);


    public void setOrderAndFilter(String order, Query.Direction direction, String filterString) {

        mOrder = order;
        mDirection = direction;
        mFilter = filterString;

        Query mChartsQuery = getQuery(mDatabaseRef, mOrder, mDirection);

        // Update recycler options
        FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Chart> recyclerOptions = new FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Chart>()
                .setQuery(mChartsQuery, Chart.class)
                .build();

        mAdapter = new ChartListAdapter(recyclerOptions, getActivity());
        mAdapter.startListening();

        mRecycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mChartsQuery.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {

                if (queryDocumentSnapshots != null) {

                    // Hide "loading lists" text
                    mLoadingList.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    if(queryDocumentSnapshots.size() > 0) {
                        mEmptyList.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        mRecycler.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else {
                        // If number of Charts = 0,
                        //    if we have filtered, show "no results"
                        //    otherwise, show "no charts"
                        mEmptyList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        mRecycler.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }
```

This references the `ChartListAdapter` class, which is defined like this:

```
public class ChartListAdapter extends FirestoreRecyclerAdapter<Chart, ChartViewHolder> {

    private Activity mActivity;

    public ChartListAdapter(FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Chart> recyclerOptions, Activity activity) {
        super(recyclerOptions);

        mActivity = activity;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ChartViewHolder holder, int position, @NonNull Chart model) {

        final String chartKey = this.getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getId();

        model.setKey(chartKey);

        // Set click listener for the chart
        // On click, the user can view the chart
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, ActivityViewChart.class);
                intent.putExtra("ChartKey", chartKey);
                mActivity.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // Implement long-click menu
        mActivity.registerForContextMenu(holder.itemView);

        // Bind Chart to ViewHolder
        holder.bindToChart(model);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ChartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_chart, parent, false);

        return new ChartViewHolder(view);
    }

}
```

So, currently this retrieves all of the current user's charts, and sorts and displays them.  What I want to be able to do is filter the results, so the user can enter some search text, and only charts whose names or descriptions contain that text are shown.

My understanding is that I can't do this as part of the Firestore query, so my idea was to retrieve the full list of charts, and then loop over them all, remove any that don't meet the criteria, and then show the rest (there are unlikely to be hundreds of charts in the list; most users will have around 10).

I can't figure out how to do this, and I'm not even sure whether it's the best way. The obvious place to do it seems to be when I add the `snapshotListener` to the `ChartsQuery` in `FragmentChartsList`, but I can't find a way to remove an individual snapshot from the list. Alternatively, can I put all the items into the `recyclerView` and then remove the ones that I don't want?

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Everything I've found online seems to be about removing a recyclerView item and deleting it from the database, which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following query for search filter functionality.

```
databaseReference.collection("charts")
                 .whereEqualTo("uid", getUid())
                 .orderBy("name")
                 .startAt(searchText)
                 .endAt(searchtText + "\uf8ff");
```

Pass search text to startAt() and endAt() function and name is your documentField.

And pass this query to firestoreAdapter it will provide you with the result record.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll try that now!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work... it's filtering a bit randomly.  From reading the documentation on startAt, it looks like this works on the document level, so it's filtering on the Chart id, not the name/description?

Comment: The above query only filters on the name, not on chart id. And it at a time work only on one document filed. example name or chart id, or description that you pass in orderBy("document filed"). You need to decide on which field you want to filter. And if you want to filter on all then you need to go for the custom adapter. It will not work with firestore adapter@Sharon